# Need help booting a Red Hat Linux 6.1 virtual image - Kernel panic - Unable to mount root fs

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, kernel-panic, lilo

I'm trying to virtualize a Red Hat Linux 6.1 image. I restored a clonezilla backup on a .vmdk and I'm trying to get the image to boot successfully in the latest release of VirtualBox 5. Unsurprisingly, I'm getting a Kernel panic. Bootloader is lilo. Disk is on a SCSI (BusLogic) controller in VBox. 500MB of ram. Chipset PIIX3. Audio,Network,Serial, USB all disabled.

I would like to preface this post by saying that I am not the one who designed/partitioned this image and that my knowledge of linux is average at best.

Please see the screenshots.
[Image 1](https://ibb.co/cL326ts)
[Image 2](https://ibb.co/PcDpRMh)

```
VFS: Mounted root (ext2 filesystem).
Loading aic7xxx module
scsi : 0 hosts.
/lib/aic7xxx.o: init_module: Device or resource busy
autodetecting RAID arrays
autorun...
... autorun DONE.
kmod: failed to exec /sbin/modprobe -s -k block-major-8, errno = 2
VFS: Cannot open root device 08:03
Kernel panic: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on 08:03
```

fstab:

```
/dev/sda3       /         ext2    defaults       1 1
/dev/sda2       /boot     ext2    defaults       1 2
/dev/sda4       /abc      ext2    defaults       1 2
/dev/sda1       swap      swap    defaults       0 0
none            /proc     proc    defaults       0 0
none            /dev/pts  devpts  gid=5,mode=620 0 0
```

lilo.conf:

```
boot=/dev/sda
map=/boot/map
install=/boot/boot.b
prompt
tiemout=50
default=linux

#Default kernel ( orig )
image=/boot/vmlinuz-2.2-12-20
    append="mem=376M"
    label=linux
    initrd=/boot/initrd-2.2.12-20.img
    read-only
    root=/dev/sda3
```

When i try to boot with SystemRecovery live cd, it fails at "Checking root filesystem" and says my root partition (/dev/sda3) is mounted. Cannot continue, aborting.
If i select Control-D for normal startup, it performs fsck on the other 2 partitions(/dev/sda2 and /dev/sda4) and then it just hangs.

I've used a livecd and I've succesfully mounted the partitions and even did a fsck on them to see if that would help. No luck. All clean btw.

Not sure if the AIC7xxx SCSI driver is causing problems... obviously the VM doesn't have an Adaptec SCSI controller...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: RHEL 6.1 = 2011 update. The last update was 6.10, June 2020. End of life was 'November 10, 2010' . ....... Suggest CentOS 6.10 / RHEL 6.10 .

Comment: @KnudLarsen it’s worse than that,  this isn’t RHEL6, it’s Red Hat Linux 6.1, released in 1999.  You can tell from the v2.2.12 Linux kernel.

Comment: I wonder if running a modern fsck on a 20+ year old ext2 filesystem made it incompatible with the kernel ext2 driver from that era?